# Set Cell in GtkTreeView to edit mode programmatically

Tags: c++, gtk

I currently write an application that has a `GtkTreeView` with a `GtkCellRendererText` which property `editable` is set to true. When double clicking an item, I can edit it. Now I want to be able to add an empty row and immediately start editing it. I tried using `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor_on_cell` with `start_editing` set to true. It selects the row, but it does not start editing. I put together a small example (please not that I do not have any error checking in place as its just a small example).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkListStore  *store;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *view;
GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *vbox;


void sig_inserted(GtkTreeModel *model, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeIter *iter)
{
    // Set cursor on cell with start_editing = TRUE
    gtk_tree_view_set_cursor_on_cell(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), path, gtk_tree_view_get_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), 0), renderer, TRUE);
}

void button_clicked(GtkButton *button, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    // Add empty row to liststore
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 0, "", -1);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "delete_event", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    view = gtk_tree_view_new ();

    // Create renderer and set editable to TRUE
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
    GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&val, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN);
    g_value_set_boolean(&val, TRUE);
    g_object_set_property(G_OBJECT(renderer), "editable", &val);
    g_value_unset(&val);

    // Insert Text column
    gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes (GTK_TREE_VIEW (view),
                                               -1,      
                                               "Name",  
                                               renderer,
                                               "text", 0,
                                               NULL);

    store = gtk_list_store_new (1, G_TYPE_STRING);

    // Add test item
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                      0, "Test",
                      -1);

    gtk_tree_view_set_model (GTK_TREE_VIEW (view), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(0,0);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Add edit item");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);



    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(store), "row-inserted", G_CALLBACK(sig_inserted), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), NULL);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `g++` (as I do not comply with all C needs) using

```
g++ -o tree tree.cc `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

It would also work with Gtk3 I think as nothing seems to have changed in the things I use.

Can somebody point me out why it does not start editing?

Comment: If you comment out `gtk_list_store_set`, everything works as expected. Maybe this functions automatically makes model think, that editing has ended. (Tested with gtk3 only)

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Post that as an answer an I will accept it!

Comment: Now that's knowledge :)

Comment: thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk_list_store_set` cancels editing of a cell. Commenting out this line makes everything work.

---

It can be found this with a little modification to code:

```
void sig_inserted(GtkTreeModel *model, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeIter *iter)
{
    GtkTreeViewColumn * col = gtk_tree_view_get_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), 0);
    // Set cursor on cell with start_editing = TRUE
    g_message ("sig_inserted", __LINE__);
    gtk_tree_view_set_cursor_on_cell(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), path, col, renderer, TRUE);
}

void button_clicked(GtkButton *button, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    // Add empty row to liststore
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    g_message ("Clicked");
    gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
    g_message ("Appended");
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 0, "x", -1);
    g_message ("Set");
}

void
estart (GtkCellRenderer *renderer,
        GtkCellEditable *editable,
        gchar           *path,
        gpointer         user_data)
{
    g_message ("renderer: start edit");
}

void
ecancel (GtkCellRenderer *renderer,
         gpointer         user_data)
{
    g_message ("renderer: cancel edit");
}
```

And connecting to renderers signals:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(renderer), "editing-started", G_CALLBACK(estart), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(renderer), "editing-canceled", G_CALLBACK(ecancel), NULL);
```

Give the following output:

`** Message: Clicked
** Message: sig_inserted
** Message: renderer: start edit
** Message: Appended
** Message: renderer: cancel edit
** Message: Set`